# F-space and completely regular space

Tags: general-topology

A completely regular space X is an F-space if for each functionally open set $M\subset X$ every continous function $f: M \rightarrow I $ continuously extendable over X.

I want to prove that a completely regular space X is an F-space iff any two disjoint sets functionally open in X are completely separated.
$(\leftarrow :)$ It is known that any disjoint functionally closed sets A,B in X are completelty separated.Hence, every disjoint functionally open sets are completely separated. So, one side is clear.
$(:\rightarrow )$ For the other side , lets take a functionally open set M and take a continuous function $f:M\rightarrow I$. I need a two disjoint functionally open set in X. One of them is M. For the other, I take $N={f^{-1}}(0)$ is functionally closed and complement of N in X is functionally open.  I say $N^{c}\cap M=\emptyset$.   If it is true, then I can use the completely separated property. then there exists a continous function $h:X\rightarrow I$ such that $h(x)=0$ for each $x\in M$ and  $h(x)=1$for each $x\in N^{c}$ Hence,  can we say h is the extension of f over X?

Comment: Sorry, what is 'functionally open'? And exactly which point are you uncertain?

Comment: @Berci: A functionally open set is what some of us know as a cozero-set: it’s the inverse image of an open set under some continuous real-valued function $f:X\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: No, you can’t say that $N^c\cap M=\varnothing$: that’s true only if $M\subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$, which is true iff $f$ is the zero function on $M$.

Comment: you are right.. So, could you give me any hint?

Comment: I’m thinking about it.

Comment: Since X is completely regular and $X\setminus M$ closed,there exists a continous function $k:X\rightarrow I$ such that for each $x \notin X\setminus M$,  $k(x)=0$ and for each $y\in X\setminus M$,  $h(y)=1$. Then $M\subset {k^{-1}}(0)$ and we take $N={k^{-1}}(0)$. Then complement of N and M are disjoint functionally open set. So, these are completely separated.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: $\mathbb{R}$ is a F-space?

Comment: @M.Sina: No: $U=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ is functionally open, and the floor function is continuous on $U$, but it can’t be extended continuously to $\Bbb R$.